# dropdown hover hidden in overflow-y

Tags: html, css

I am new to the CSS. I am facing the problem, which is when I put the overflow into my sidebar. The scrollbar come correctly, but the hover item will be hidden. Hope to get help.

```css
.sidebar-left.open .sidebar_nav .sidebar_nav-main {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px)
}

.sidebar-left.open .dropdown .sidebar-subchild-hover .dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-left.open .dropdown:hover .sidebar-subchild-hover .dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: did u put a z-index on the hover menu yet? Please add HTML so we can actually see what happens within the widget.

Comment: @FUZIION Yes, I had tried put z-index on the hover menu before, but hover menu still hidden.  Sorry I just want to update my html but it only allow me post once in 90minute.

Comment: _"but it only allow me post once in 90minute"_ - maybe for asking _new_ question, but you should be able to edit an existing one.

Comment: Yes, I was edited and add my html code as image for reference. Thankyou...

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: Great that you found the solution, but please refrain from posting code screenshots. Next time insert a small portion of HTML inside the code widget. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP found their answer in @CBroe's comment posting about the [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) which includes this exact issue.

For reference and other people having similar issues with this, I will include some code snippets and information from the article.

If we omit the `position: relative` from the menu items, the submenus do show up, positioned based on their closest positioned ancestor. In this case, they don’t have a positioned ancestor, so they’re positioned relative to :

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 75%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
}

li ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li ul {
  cursor: auto;
}

li ul li {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #0e8ce0;
}

li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #0064b3;
}

li.parent {
  background: #00b99b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Abc</li>
  <li>Jkl</li>
  <li class="parent">Mno >
    <ul>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
      <li class="parent">Mno >
        <ul>
          <li>Abc</li>
          <li>Def</li>
          <li>Ghi</li>
          <li>Jkl</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Pqr</li>
      <li>Xyz</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Basically, in order for an absolutely positioned element to appear outside of an element with `overflow: hidden`, its closest positioned ancestor must also be an ancestor of the element with `overflow: hidden`.

Knowing this, we can add a wrapper around the menus to act as the closest positioned ancestor for each submenu. Then, whenever the user hovers over a menu item, we can position the submenu wrappers using a bit of JavaScript:

```js
$(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  $('li.parent').on('mouseover', function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this),
      $submenuWrapper = $('> .wrapper', $menuItem);

    // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent
    var menuItemPos = $menuItem.position();

    // place the submenu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
    $submenuWrapper.css({
      top: menuItemPos.top,
      left: menuItemPos.left + Math.round($menuItem.outerWidth() * 0.75)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: static;
}

li .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

li:hover>.wrapper {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
}

li ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li .wrapper {
  cursor: auto;
}

li .wrapper li {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #0e8ce0;
}

li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #0064b3;
}

li.parent {
  background: #00b99b;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Abc</li>
    <li>Jkl</li>
    <li class="parent">Mno >
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>Abc</li>
          <li>Jkl</li>
          <li class="parent">Mno >
            <div class="wrapper">
              <ul>
                <li>Abc</li>
                <li>Def</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>Pqr</li>
          <li>Xyz</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>Pqr</li>
    <li>Stu</li>
    <li>Vw</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```